# How to trace multiple providers with xperf

Tags: perfmon, xperf

Xperf only lets you run one kernel session. The syntax for creating a kernel session for one provider is `xperf -start MySession -on 2DA81B52-908E-7DB6-EF81-76856BB47C4F` However, I cannot seem to specify multiple providers. The following does not work:

- Multiple on switches `-on A9377239-477A-DD22-6E21-75912A95FD08 -on BA798F36-2325-EC5B-ECF8-76958A2AF9B5`
- Comma separated `-on A9377239-477A-DD22-6E21-75912A95FD08,BA798F36-2325-EC5B-ECF8-76958A2AF9B5`
- Space separated with or without quotes `-on A9377239-477A-DD22-6E21-75912A95FD08 BA798F36-2325-EC5B-ECF8-76958A2AF9B5`  or `-on "A9377239-477A-DD22-6E21-75912A95FD08 BA798F36-2325-EC5B-ECF8-76958A2AF9B5"`

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is using plus as a delimiter.

```
xperf -start MySession -on 2DA81B52-908E-7DB6-EF81-76856BB47C4F+A9377239-477A-DD22-6E21-75912A95FD08+BA798F36-2325-EC5B-ECF8-76958A2AF9B5
```